# Adding suspension forks to rigid bicycle

Tags: mountain-bike

I'm thinking of adding suspension forks to a rigid mtb. I realized that the geometry will change with the front higher and so the chain will be slanted up. Does this affect how hard and tiring is it to pedal and the steering. If I were to do it, how much travel of suspension do I need, or should I just stick to the rigid.

Comment: It should change the geometry much unless you raise the handlebar height. Get a fork with lock-out capabilities for hill climbing. Then enjoy the suspension comfort for bumpy ride. And yes, a suspension fork weight 2 times more then typical fork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can most likely switch to suspension forks without much trouble at all. The shouldn't be any real difference in how hard it is to pedal as you're still putting in the same amount of energy with the same number of turns of the cranks. The only thing i would suggest is to Stick with the **Smaller Travel Forks** as that will minimize the amount of difference that you notice in how the bike handles.

Comment: -1: because of "Without much trouble" which trivializes the problems with new standards for brakes (disc vs rim), axles (9mmqr, 15mm through 20mm though, 9mm thru) and steerers (1", 1 1/8", 1.5" and Tapered) and travel. The number of permutations of fork available and compatability with a particular bike make this "with no trouble if you have no trouble getting a compatible fork"

Comment: The steerer tube of this rigid bicycle fork is 1 inch in diamter and therefore I need to get a compatible fork. I know that there are not much of those out there, but there still are. Any recommendations for a suspension fork 1 inch in size and not too expensive?

Comment: Your best bet is a 2008 or 2009 Marzocchi MX Pro ETA.  Finding one is a bit of an issue, and cost is likely USD 300+.

Comment: I think I will just buy another hardtail bicycle in that case.